# Conexión con la Api de Zendesk

Tags: c#, json

Hola estoy trabajando en una conexión con Zendesk para crear un ticket, ya tengo creado mi formulario, estoy trabajando con Visual Studio y mi proyecto es de tipo Aplicación Web ASP.NET (.NET FRAMEWORK) y estoy intentando usar **HttpWebRequest**, en la autenticación quiero hacerlo por medio de un token (su estructura es más o menos así lrVG63Ftyucm24uydWfgcQWdfgEtfC45) pero no he encontrado cómo hacerlo, así que lo estaba haciendo poniendo un correo y contraseña de usuario, pero si me pueden ayudar a hacerlo con token se los agradecería mucho, esto es lo que se debe ejecutar al momento de hacer clic en el botón de enviar:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;


namespace Formulario.Public
{
public partial class SendTicket : System.Web.UI.Page
{
 
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void SendButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        saludo.Text = "datos enviados";
        ValidacionModel jsonObject = new ValidacionModel();
        jsonObject.request = new Request() {
            email = "prueba@correo.com",
            name = "Ana",
            classification = "Facturación",
            subject = "Test",
            description = "test sndndddjiwd djw"
        };

        // Json conversion
        JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        settings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        string jsonTicket = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObject, settings);

        string postData = jsonTicket;
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

        HttpWebRequest request;
        request = WebRequest.Create("https://prueba.zendesk.com/api/v2/requests.json") as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Timeout = 10 * 1000;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

        string credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("prueba@correo.com:password123"));
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + credentials);

        Stream postStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

        HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        string body = reader.ReadToEnd();

    }
  }
}
```

Al momento de ejecutar el proyecto me manda el siguiente error:
[image: descripción del error]

Comment: Según veo tu código, tengo la sensación que sabes por dónde vas, `pero no he encontrado cómo hacerlo`, aquí te alcanzo 2 cosas: https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/api-clients/dotnet para que veas código de otros programadores y la documentación oficial https://develop.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001073988-Use-the-Zendesk-APIs Estaré al pendiente de esta pregunta por si requieres más ayuda :D Éxitos con el desarollo :D

Comment: Hola @fredyfx gracias por tu aporte, honestamente no tengo experiencia en c#, lo que llevo echo es porque me fui guiando de ejemplos de internet, mi duda es con el uso del  **HttpWebRequest** ya no que no logro hacer la conexión, como primer paso me gustaría lograr la conexión con zendesk, pero no logro hacerlo, o si sabes de alguna otra manera de hacer la conexión te lo agradecería mucho. Saludos

Comment: interesante, para no tener experiencia, vas por buen camino: creas un objeto, lo serializas, luego lo envías. Ese error es porque el servidor no ha recibido lo que esperaba y por lo tanto no puede procesarlo, fíjate bien en la documentación. Toma un momento para ver los enlaces mencionados, sé que te guiarán por buen camino, intenta y con lo nuevo que hayas intentado, actualiza tu pregunta. Por otro lado, mira la HTTPWebRequest en: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest?view=netframework-4.0 Esto te ayudará a entender el error: https://httpstatuses.com/422